# How to type special character-- a Y with a line through it

Tags: symbols, characters

The symbol I'm looking for is similar to the one produced by `\mathfrak{X}`, but with a Y instead of an X.  I've spent hours looking for this, combed through every character list I can find, tried detexify, and I can't find the answer anywhere.  If this question has been asked before, I apologize, please direct me to it, I've looked and haven't found it.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Should the Y be fraktur too?

Comment: Have you got any picture of your Y? I hope that it is not the symbol of yen...

Comment: @egreg Yes, it is exactly like the X, just with a Y.  

And no,@Przemysław Scherwentke, it is not the symbol for yen.  Let me figure out how to upload a picture and I will.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I can't upload a picture, so here's a work-around.  Go to this [link](https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Winter-School-Proceedings-Mathematics/dp/3540071903?ie=UTF8&*Version*=1&*entries*=0), you can preview the book.  The character I'm looking for is at the top of page 231.

Comment: Is it an article of Wojbor Wojczyński? I have not previev of this page, but a visible part is from pre-computer era.

Comment: @A.R. It's difficult to say what stem should have the bar through it.

Comment: I don't seem to have access to p. 231 of the book via the link you posted. Can you sketch the character by hand on a piece of the and post a scan of the drawing?

Comment: @Mico I tried that but I couldn't figure out how to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is not exactly clear if you want a normal "Y" or a fraktur "Y", I provide both... (note that these are designed to take up the same space as an unadulterated "Y" or `\mathfrak{Y}`)

The stoke elevation can be adjusted with the first argument of `\stackengine`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\strokeY{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{-\,}{Y}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\def\strokefracY{\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{\,-}{\mathfrak{Y}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}}}
\begin{document}
$\strokeY =  X$

$\strokefracY =  X$
\end{document}
```

[image]